# Object Oriented Communication with WCF

Tags: wcf, object, communication

I know that WCF is a message passing system, with specified `Service Contract` interface declaring methods that can return or take as argument instances of `Data Contract` classes.

My question is : Is it possible to use WCF to implement a kind of Object Oriented Communication? For instance :

- Could a `Service Contract` interface method return another `Service Contract` ? This would enable me to create a tree of instances, first step of Object Oriented Communication.
- Even better, could a `Service Contract` implement not only methods but also properties?

If you have any other idea to create this kind of Object Oriented Communication, please let me know. I'm a bit stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in order:

1. WCF allows you to return an interface from a contract method. But all implementations of that interface that you plan to use in the service need to be known to the service (via `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute` or by decorating them with `DataContract`), otherwise you'll run into serialization issues.
2. No, only methods are allowed. This is how it works. Imagine how proxies' implementations (generated or not) would look like if it were to support properties. A lot of complications for something that could easily be solved with methods.

On how could you do it... I'm assuming this is all from the client's perspective.
So, on the client you can create a wrapper over the service proxy and make it expose properties and other *contracts*, as you've called them. The contracts can be wrappers over other service proxies (or the same, depends what you need).

So, the bottom line is that you have to emulate what you ask for, directly on the client.

You should not consider stretching/extending WCF much over what it can do by default, but write your own framework over it, only if really needed. WCF by itself can handle a lot of scenarios and maybe you just need to adjust your requirements or technical design a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! As it doesn't work exactly as I need it to, I think I'll try to build a small framework on the client and on the server side that helps me doing this.